# Access input forms of an existing page using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm playing around with Google Chrome Extensions and wanted to make one where you fill out a form beforehand. Then whenever, a certain URL is opened, it fills in the information you filled out. I can save the information, and track the tab URL with one of Google's packages. However, when the URL is loaded, how can I tell what form to put the saved strings into? I know how to use `var.document.getElementById("")`, and can see the `id`s when I inspect element, but since it's not my webpage, I can't link it to my JavaScript file, so it doesn't help. I've seen this been done before but just can't find the right tools. Any guidance to an answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Whot! var.document.getElementById("")? :) You really need to rewrite this question

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be sure to read our [ask] page to help you formulate a great question.  You are much more likely to get a good answer from the community if you put some effort into your question.

Comment: Seen tampermonkey? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en